# Cannot instantiate yaml variable list with evironment variables: Could not resolve placeholder in value

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I am trying to set some environment variables in a list in my `application.yaml` file, however I am getting the following error message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'SOME_ID' in value
> "${SOME_ID},${ANOTHER_ID}"

I have the following value in my `application.yaml` file:

```
com:
  foo:
    product-ids: ${SOME_ID},${ANOTHER_ID}
```

where these values are set in some other yaml files such as so:

```
application:
  env: test

subEnv:
  - name: SOME_ID
    value: "foo"
  - name: ANOTHER_ID
    value: "bar"
```

And my service looks like the following:

```
@Service
public class Service {
  private final List<String> productIds;

  public Service(
          @Value("#{'${com.foo.product-ids}'.split(',')}") List<String> productIds) {
    this.productIds = productIds;
  }
  ...
}
```

and my initilizer for my tests looks like so:

```
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = {Service.class},
    initializers = {SpringBootComponentTest.Initializer.class})
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = {Service.class})
@SpringJUnitConfig
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class SpringBootComponentTest {

  protected static final String FIRST_VALUE = "abc";
  protected static final String SECOND_VALUE = "xyz";
...
  static class Initializer
      implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
      TestPropertyValues.of(
              "com.foo.product-ids[0]=" + FIRST_VALUE,
              "com.foo.product-ids[1]=" + SECOND_VALUE)
          .applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
    }
  }
}
```

Also, it appears that the issue subsides if I just replace the variable reference to a hard coded value like

```
com:
  foo:
    product-ids: foo,bar
```

but this is not the solution that I am looking for; I want to be able to add my variables to this list.

Edit: Here is the majority/relevant data from my `application.yaml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-service
server:
  port: 8080
management:
  endpoint:
    metrics:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
  endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"
  server:
    port: 9080
  security:
    enabled: false
  metrics:
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
    distribution:
      sla:
        http.server.requests: ${CORE_COMMON_BACKEND_SLA:PT1S}
com:
  foo:
    product-ids: ${SOME_ID},${ANOTHER_ID}
```

Edit 2:

I should note that I can access these variables just fine if I do NOT use a list.

So if I do something like:

```
com:
  foo:
    product-id1: ${SOME_ID}
    proudct-id2: ${ANOTHER_ID}
```

and modify the code accordingly, this works, but I still do not want this as my solution.

For some reason it appears that referencing a variable in my `products-ids` list is the issue...

Comment: You should post full content of `application.yml`

Answer (score 0):

It regards to the order in which the spring boot load your YAML config file. [Detail here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config)

In your case, the order 13 & 15 are applied.

So, you should naming your environment-specific config file: **application-test.yaml** as you used @ActiveProfiles("test") in your test case.

And then your **application.yaml** should load the properties from environment-specific config file correctly.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understood you correctly,...I already have an application-test.yaml file, but that only contains stuff regarding log levels. Also, I think I should mention that there are a lot of other fields in the ´initialize' method where I am assigning random test values for other property fields, which I omitted and are not relevant to this issue, so I would think that this part should be fine.